# How to separate a string's regex matches from its non-matches and maintain its original order?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to emulate the behavior of a failing `expect(s).not.toMatch(/regex/)` in your typical test framework. Right now I'm generating an error message that tells you a match *was* found, tells you what the regex was and prints the "haystack" it searched in.

I'd like to improve this error message. I want to color code all of the matches in the haystack (not just the first) so the user doesn't have to expend as much effort to find them on their own. I already have a library to color code text. What I'm lacking is the algorithm to:

1. Split the haystack's matches from its non-matches
2. Identify which parts are matches and which parts are non-matches
3. Return a value that can be reconstructed back into its original form (with or without color coding, whatever's easiest to implement)
4. Works with most regexes

Based on my searches, that last point is unique. All the other questions I found are using a literal regex, but mine will be dynamic and unknown to the algorithm. That means the regex may already contain capture groups. e.g., `expect(s).not.toMatch(/(foo|bar)/)` or `expect(s).not.toMatch(/baz/)` or `expect(s).not.toMatch(/(?:foo|bar)/)`. I would want the implementation to provide something useful under these conditions.

So far, I've attempted to come up with a solution that uses `string.match()`, `string.split()`, and `regex.match()`, but most fail to address all the above requirements, particularly point 3. I have an inkling that I'm using the wrong tool for the job and maybe I just need to know something that exists in order to solve the problem on my own.

---

### Examples of what I've tried

```js
function withSplit(actualValue, re) {
  const matches = [...(actualValue + '').split(new RegExp(`(${re.source})`, `g`))];
  console.log(`matches`, matches, `actualValue`, actualValue, `re`, re, `\nissue: which ones are matches?`);
}

withSplit(`foo bar baz`, /foo/);

function withMatchAllWrapInGroup(actualValue, re) {
  const matches = [...(actualValue + '').matchAll(new RegExp(`(${re.source})`, `g`))];
  console.log(`matches`, matches, `actualValue`, actualValue, `re`, re, `\nissue: doesn't print non-matches`);
}

withMatchAllWrapInGroup(`foo bar baz`, /foo/);

function withMatchAll(actualValue, re) {
  const matches = [...(actualValue + '').matchAll(new RegExp(re.source, `g`))];
  console.log(`matches`, matches, `actualValue`, actualValue, `re`, re, `\nissue: doesn't print non-matches`);
}

withMatchAll(`foo bar baz`, /foo/);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll? That gives you both the text that matched and its starting index, from which it would be straightforward to format accordingly.

Comment: porbably a good Idea to post an example of what you've tried. also you can just use the contains / includes methods to check strings for substrings

Comment: May also want to include sanitization and/or run it in a worker thread with a timeout so the regex can't hold the program hostage. Too easy to write a regex that looks okay but is awful.

Comment: `match.index` and `match[0].length` are all you need. If you care about overlapping matches, use `exec` with a global regex and reset `lastIndex` to `match.index`. If not, what @jonrsharpe said.

Comment: I added some examples of what I've tried.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How would I perform 3. with this?

Comment: @Ry- Can you clarify what you mean by "If you care about overlapping matches?" If I care *in what way*? I haven't been able to find a regex that returns overlapping matches with `matchAll`. Is that what you meant; `matchAll` will always return a single match even if multiple matches overlap?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant.

Comment: @Ry- I'm impressed: as far as I can tell, that's not documented on MDN's [matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) page. Good timing too, because [I just created a separate question about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77706361/can-string-prototype-matchall-return-overlapping-matches)

Answer (score 0):

#### The Algorithm

The following code is written in typescript.

```
export type SplitMatchElement = {
  value: string;
  isMatch: boolean;
};

export type SplitMatchArray = SplitMatchElement[];

export const splitMatches = (haystack: string, re: RegExp): SplitMatchArray => {
  const result: SplitMatchArray = [];
  const matchMetadata = [...haystack.matchAll(new RegExp(re.source, `g`))].map(
    (match) => {
      return {
        matchStartIndex: match.index,
        matchLength: match[0].length,
      };
    }
  );

  if (matchMetadata.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }

  let substringStart = 0;
  matchMetadata.forEach(({ matchStartIndex, matchLength }) => {
    if (substringStart < matchStartIndex) {
      result.push({
        value: haystack.substring(substringStart, matchStartIndex),
        isMatch: false,
      });
      substringStart = matchStartIndex;
    }

    if (substringStart >= matchStartIndex) {
      result.push({
        value: haystack.substring(
          substringStart,
          matchStartIndex + matchLength
        ),
        isMatch: true,
      });
      substringStart = matchStartIndex + matchLength;
    }
  });

  if (substringStart < haystack.length - 1) {
    result.push({
      value: haystack.substring(substringStart),
      isMatch: false,
    });
  }

  return result;
};
```

#### Additional Context

Okay, here's the subtle detail that completely threw me off: `console.log(matches)` **does not print all the properties described in [the exec() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#return_value)**. If you use `console.log()` to learn the shape of the `matchAll` return value (and other similar functions), it will mislead you. You have to explicitly look for the properties by name to see them:

```js
const matchAllSplat = [...`foo bar baz`.matchAll(/(foo|bar)/g)];
$(`#match-all-splat`).text(JSON.stringify(matchAllSplat));

const matchAllReturn = `foo bar baz`.matchAll(/(foo|bar)/g);
for (const match of matchAllReturn) {
  $(`#match-all-json-stringify`).append(`<p>${JSON.stringify(match)}</p>`);
}

const matchAllPropertyDescriptor = `foo bar baz`.matchAll(/(foo|bar)/g);
$(`#match-all-property-descriptor`).append(`<p>[</p>`);
for (const match of matchAllPropertyDescriptor) {
  const propertyDescriptors = (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(match).map((propName) => {
    return propName + ": " + JSON.stringify(match[propName])
  }).join(", "));
  $(`#match-all-property-descriptor`).append(`<p class="tabbed">{ ${propertyDescriptors} }, &lt;!--- Array with special properties ---&gt; </p>`);
}
$(`#match-all-property-descriptor`).append(`<p>]</p>`);
```

```css
.tabbed {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Match All Splat</h1>
<div id="match-all-splat"></div>
<h1>Match All JSON.stringify Each Element</h1>
<div id="match-all-json-stringify"></div>
<h1>Match All JSON.stringify Each Element's Property Descriptor</h1>
<div id="match-all-property-descriptor"></div>
```

Once you are aware those properties exist, the algorithm becomes (relatively) straightforward.

#### (Node.JS) Test Cases

These won't run on the web, but AFAIK, it's the only way to hide block of code on the site.

```js
import {
  splitMatches
} from './split-matches';

describe(`splitMatches`, () => {
  it('returns an empty array if there are no matches', async() => {
    expect(splitMatches(`foo bar baz`, /qux/)).toEqual([]);
  });

  it('returns a single match if haystack and regex completely overlap', async() => {
    expect(splitMatches(`foo bar baz`, /foo bar baz/)).toEqual([{
      value: `foo bar baz`,
      isMatch: true,
    }, ]);
  });

  it('returns a match and non-match when regex matches beginning of haystack', async() => {
    expect(splitMatches(`foo bar baz`, /foo bar /)).toEqual([{
        value: `foo bar `,
        isMatch: true,
      },
      {
        value: `baz`,
        isMatch: false,
      },
    ]);
  });

  it('returns a non-match and match when regex matches end of haystack', async() => {
    expect(splitMatches(`foo bar baz`, /baz/)).toEqual([{
        value: `foo bar `,
        isMatch: false,
      },
      {
        value: `baz`,
        isMatch: true,
      },
    ]);
  });

  it('returns a non-match, match, and non-match when regex matches middle of haystack', async() => {
    expect(splitMatches(`foo bar baz`, /bar/)).toEqual([{
        value: `foo `,
        isMatch: false,
      },
      {
        value: `bar`,
        isMatch: true,
      },
      {
        value: ` baz`,
        isMatch: false,
      },
    ]);
  });

  it('returns a match, non-match, and match when regex matches edges of haystack', async() => {
    expect(splitMatches(`foo bar baz`, /(foo | baz)/)).toEqual([{
        value: `foo `,
        isMatch: true,
      },
      {
        value: `bar`,
        isMatch: false,
      },
      {
        value: ` baz`,
        isMatch: true,
      },
    ]);
  });

  it('returns the full match when .* is in the regex', async() => {
    expect(splitMatches(`foo bar baz`, /o .* b/)).toEqual([{
        value: `fo`,
        isMatch: false,
      },
      {
        value: `o bar b`,
        isMatch: true,
      },
      {
        value: `az`,
        isMatch: false,
      },
    ]);
  });
});
```