# Can String.prototype.matchAll() return overlapping matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to pass [String.prototype.matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) a regex that will return overlapping matches? Every idea I've come up with chooses one match when multiple could work:

```js
function logMatches(str, re) {
  console.log(`"${str}".matchAll(/${re.source}/${re.flags}) = [`);
  [...str.matchAll(re)].map(matchProperties).forEach((props) => {
    console.log("\t", props);
  })
  console.log("];");
  console.log();
}

function matchProperties(match) {
  return "{ " + (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(match).map((propName) => {
    return propName + ": " + JSON.stringify(match[propName])
  }).join(", ")) + " }, // Note: this element is an Array";
}

logMatches("foo bar baz", /foo|baz/g); // no overlap expected
logMatches("foo bar baz", / .*/g);
logMatches("foo bar baz", /b.*/g);
logMatches("foo bar baz", /b.*?/g);  // no overlap expected
logMatches("foo bar baz", /ba.*$/g);
logMatches("foo bar baz", /ba| .* /g);
```

Here's what I expected to see from that last example (the first two elements overlap):

```
"foo bar baz".matchAll(/ba| .* /g) = [
     { 0: " bar ", length: 1, index: 3, input: "foo bar baz", groups: undefined }, // Note: this element is an Array
     { 0: "ba", length: 1, index: 4, input: "foo bar baz", groups: undefined }, // Note: this element is an Array
     { 0: "ba", length: 1, index: 8, input: "foo bar baz", groups: undefined }, // Note: this element is an Array
];
```

Is this the way `matchAll` works or does it have something to do with regular expressions in general? Or, and this might be more likely, is a bug in my example code?

Comment: I don't know if this is important but [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77700765/how-to-separate-a-strings-regex-matches-from-its-non-matches-and-maintain-its-o?noredirect=1#comment136984187_77700765) spurred my question.

Comment: Are you able to maybe share what your expected results would be? Perhaps making it a [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301298/5648954) regex instead of greedy of what you're after? (eg:  `/b.*?/g`)

Comment: The duplicate shows how to do it directly (using lookaheads) or also the way suggested in the comment that you refer to.

Comment: Aside from the answers provided at the duplicate target, you can also inherit from `RegExp` and implement your own `[Symbol.matchAll]()` method that converts lookahead matches into normal-looking ones.

Comment: @InSync `you can also inherit from RegExp and implement your own [Symbol.matchAll]() method that converts lookahead matches into normal-looking ones.` Wouldn't that be the opposite behavior? I thought lookahead matches are the way to get overlaps.

Comment: By "*lookahead matches*" I mean those with `[0] === ''` (e.g. `'12345'.match(/(?=(\d{3}))/)`). The conversion is easy enough: call `.shift()` to remove that group and return the same match.

Comment: FWIW, I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77706587) with a reference implementation of this idea.

Comment: @InSync Okay that makes perfect sense to me now. Thanks for the explanation. I feel like this may have been explained to me already or it's right in front of my face, but is it possible to use the lookahead technique *and* include the lookahead in the match so `[0] ===` the entire match?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `'12345'.matchAll(new OverlappingRegExp('\\d{3}', 'dg'))` already returns matches whose `[0]` equals to that of the entire matched content.

Comment: @InSync I mean without using `OverlappingRegExp` or [what you said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77706361/can-string-prototype-matchall-return-overlapping-matches?noredirect=1#comment136994499_77706361). I think the answer is no because the only way to do that would be to "consume," and that's what prevented overlap in the first place.

Comment: `OverlappingRegExp` is just syntactic sugar over what is contained in the method itself, and the method is basically the same as what is explained in [the most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33903830). A pure `RegExp` when called with `.matchAll()` cannot yield such results as the native method does no such thing; you have to write the functionality yourself, one way or another.

Comment: @InSync Okay I hoped that wasn't the case, but I understand :) Thank you again!